# regex to trim new lines within quotes

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
$string = '
Test1,One line
Test2,"Two lines 

Hello"
Test3,One line
';
```

I want to trim new lines **within** double quotation marks. So the end results will be:

```
$string = '
Test1,One line
Test2,"Two lines Hello"
Test3,One line
';
```

What's the regex approach to this?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/xgPc3G/2

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way is to match all between double quotes and replace all linebreaks with an empty string inside the matches only using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$string = '
Test1,One line
Test2,"Two lines 

Hello"
Test3,One line
';
echo preg_replace_callback('~"[^"]*"~', function($m) { 
    return preg_replace('~\R+~', '', $m[0]);
 }, $string);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/9eHb2).

Output:

```
Test1,One line
Test2,"Two lines Hello"
Test3,One line
```